# reloadDataとviewWillAppear

Tags: swift, swift2, uitableview

### viewWillAppear

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    getData()
    myTable.reloadData()
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

}
```

### getData()

```
func getData() {

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://sample.jp/api/info")
        .responseJSON { response in
            guard let object = response.result.value else {
                return
            }

            ...省略...

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.myTable.reloadData()
            }
    }

}
```

今上記のように記述しているのですがAlamofireの処理の最後にreloadDataを入れて、
viewWillAppear内で呼び出して、表示されるたびに更新しているのですが、
この際にviewWillAppear内にもreloadDataを記述する必要性はありますでしょうか。

ご回答の程よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getData()での非同期読み込みが完了してから改めてreloadしているので、viewWillApear内のreloadは意味がなく見えます。
viewWillApear内のタイミングでは情報がダウンロードされていないでしょうからreloadしても初期表示のままだと思います。

あっても害はないと思いますが、不要だと思います。

Comment: やはり不要ですよね。不安があったために確認させていただきました。ご回答ありがとうございます。